# How, in Node.js, to respond to a GET request from client (send some HTML in response)?

Tags: ajax, node.js, get, express

I have a Node.js app which, among other things, responds to a `AJAX` (`jQuery`) `$.get()` request from a Web page by sending some HTML back to that page. The app uses Express.

So in the server code, I have:

`app.get('/friends', api.friends);`, where `api` is defined as `api = require('./static/routes/api')` and i'm setting `app.use(app.router);`.

In my`api.js` module, I have `api.friends` code: I have

`exports.friends = function(request, response)`
`{`
`...lots of code...`
`};`

wherein I create some specific HTML.

Now, my question is: How do I actually send this HTML back to the client? I can't use the passed-in `response` object because this is no longer an Express-type `response` object, so the usual `reponse.send()`, `.end()`, etc. methods don't exist.

I have no idea what to do, reflecting a lack of understanding of Node and its innards (this is my first Node app), so any and all help will be greatly appreciated and welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Why is `response` no longer a an Express object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Daniel stated in his comment, the `response` object is certainly an Express object, and you can return your HTML simply by [rendering](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) a view, like so:

```
exports.friends = function(request, response) {
   //do stuff
   response.render('friends.html');
 };
```

Of course, you would have to define your views in your app.js setup, with something like this:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
```

Comment: Well, that's what I thought too. When I run my app, the error I get is:

`**.../static/routes/api.js:29 response.render(table);**`
`**TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'render'**
    at Request.exports.friends [as _callback]
    at Request.init.self.callback 
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit
    at Request.onResponseat Request.EventEmitter.emit 
    at IncomingMessage.Request.onResponse.buffer
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit
    at IncomingMessage._emitEnd 
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] 
    at CleartextStream.socketOnData`

Answer (score 0):

Ugh! I am such an idiot! In my `exports.friends` handler, there's a `request` going out which, as a part of its calling parameters, takes a function of the form `function(error, response, body)`. Note the **response** parameter. I was sending the results **within** this function, which of course used this `response` object and not the one passed through `exports.friends(request, response)`. Doh. Oh well - thank you anyway - you made me look at the code again, and with the persepctive of knowing that the `response` object was legitimate, I was able to see the error. Thank you again - appreciated!

Comment: you're welcome. It might be a good idea to edit your question with some of your code in exports.friend, as a reference for future visitors of the question.